# I want to take 2 columns from a txt file in the format YYMMDD and HHMMSS and create a datetime in format 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python/Pandas, I need to achieve the above from

0   20100301    000000  0.89894000000   0.89919000000   0.898940000 0.89916000000   0000000014

1   20100301    000100  0.89918000000   0.89919000000   0.898970000 0.89897000000   0000000015

0/1 are the indices of the first two rows.  20100301 is the date and 000000/000100 is the time.  i.e. 000100 is one minute after midnight.

Help !

I have tried all sorts !

Comment: There are no data in the file fragment that align with the stated format. Maybe you meant YYYYMMDD

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried the strftime and strptime functions from the datetime module?

Comment: Thanks for responding.   I wrognly thought that I would be emailed with responses and didn't realise I should check back.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's play with strings.

Here we are going to use a conventional approach to do this job.

**1. Pre-processing:** I assume your data is saved as a `*.txt` file like this:

```
0 20100301 000000 0.89894000000 0.89919000000 0.898940000 0.89916000000 0000000014
1 20100301 000100 0.89918000000 0.89919000000 0.898970000 0.89897000000 0000000015
```

**2. Read file as a csv:**

```
file_path = "Documents/data.txt" # based on your file address
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=" ", header=None, dtype={1:str, 2:str})
```

What do the arguments mean?
**`sep`**: columns separator, here is a space (`" "`).
**`header`**: Here our data file does not have a header (columns does not have any names)
**`dtype`**: Columns 1 & 2, containing your date and time values, is string. In case you ignore the `dtypes`, `pandas` will read these columns as integer numbers and stores `000100` as `100`.
To deeply understand these parameters, read the [documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).
Now we have this:

```
>>> df
   0         1       2        3        4        5        6   7
0  0  20100301  000000  0.89894  0.89919  0.89894  0.89916  14
1  1  20100301  000100  0.89918  0.89919  0.89897  0.89897  15
```

**3.String manipulation:** To have the date & time data, exactly in you desired format:

```
>>> df[1].str[:4]
0    2010
1    2010
Name: 1, dtype: object
>>> df[1].str[4:6]
0    03
1    03
Name: 1, dtype: object
>>> df[1].str[6:]
0    01
1    01
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

And for time data:

```
>>> df[2].str[:2]
0    00
1    00
Name: 2, dtype: object
>>> df[2].str[2:4]
0    00
1    01
Name: 2, dtype: object
>>> df[2].str[4:]
0    00
1    00
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

**IMPORTANT:** By calling `.str` attribute, we are telling Python that we need the string operations such as `.join()` or '`split()` and etc. on each row of the column.
Now we add up the strings based on your format:

```
>>> df[1].str[:4]+"-"+df[1].str[4:6]+"-"+df[1].str[6:]+" "+df[2].str[:2]+":"+df[2].str[2:4]+":"+df[2].str[4:]
0    2010-03-01 00:00:00
1    2010-03-01 00:01:00
dtype: object
```

This is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" format, if you want it to be "YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" instead, change the year part to `df[1].str[2:4]`.
Save the results in a new column:

```
df[8] = df[1].str[:4]+"-"+df[1].str[4:6]+"-"+df[1].str[6:]+" "+df[2].str[:2]+":"+df[2].str[2:4]+":"+df[2].str[4:]
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Your txt file has no header and many unnecessary columns, so I created a new example. If your original data has no header, use `header=None` in `pd.read_csv`.

**Answer**

When the top 3 rows of your CSV file are the following :

```
date time val1
20100301 000000 1
20100301 000001 2
```

You can create datetime by combining the first and second columns in the following way. (input your file path at your_file_path)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(your_file_path, sep='\s+', parse_dates={'datetime':[0, 1]})
```

`[0, 1]` means location of date & time in example file.

df

```
    datetime            val1
0   2010-03-01 00:00:00 1
1   2010-03-01 00:00:01 2
```

---

To check it simply without creating a file, use the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import io
txt = '''date time val1
20100301 000000 1
20100301 000001 2'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='\s+', parse_dates={'datetime':[0, 1]})
```

`io.StringIO` make string like file. so you can get same result

Comment: There is nothing in the question to suggest that the file has column headings

Comment: @Codist then add `header=None` as mentioned in my answer. In general, there is a header.  not seem to be a necessary comment.

Comment: You miss the point. OP has the data (in a text file) in the format shown. You can't change the data format just to make it work with your code! You make the code fit the format

Comment: @Codist I didn't change the example just to make it work with my code. Where did you get that idea? Op's data also works much more concisely if he enter the correct file name and match date & time location. of course include that if don exist header, use `header=None` like my comment. **I just made a much simpler example that is easy for everyone to understand.**

Comment: I got that idea from the fact that the data you're processing looks nothing like the example in the question

Comment: @Codist then, that is because you do not know what code can process what data. Try removing header part(`date time val1`)  from my example and running it with `header=None`. You will know that i did not make a new example for just working. you can chk easily using `io.StringIO`

Comment: @Codist You still haven't deleted your unnecessary comments, have you? The delusion of creating a header to match my code is something that **only a pandas newbie would think of**. Even [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77380035/20430449) show that it can be solved with `header=None` if there is not header. If you want to make comments that are helpful to others, please do not mention code that you do not understand, and at least check it before commenting.

Answer (score -2):

You just need the *datetime* module for this and, in particular, its *strftime()* and *strptime()* functions. *pandas* is overkill

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

with open("foo.txt") as data:
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        if line: # make sure it's not a blank line
            _, d, t, *_ = line.split()
            # parse the data
            p = DT.strptime(f"{d}{t}", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            # format the datetime
            print(DT.strftime(p, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

**Output:**

```
10-03-01 00:00:00
10-03-01 00:01:00
```